# Changing the frequency via "set_rx_freq()" is causing ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT in the metadata of the recv() command

Tags: uhd

I am setting up a USRP to record at 400MHz and receiving data correctly.  I then set up the USRP to record at 400MHz + an 18kHz offset and I get TIMEOUT errors on the recv() command.

I am setting the new frequency using the same code as the prior frequency thus that is the only thing changing in this example.

Is there some clean up or a hold time longer that 2 seconds or so that has to be done to get to a new frequency?

When the interface class is constructed we initialize using the following lines

```c
  uhd::set_thread_priority_safe();

  // Setup device addresses and create object
  uhd::device_addr_t devAddr;
  devAddr["addr0"] = "192.168.10.2";
  devAddr["addr1"] = "192.168.20.2";
  devAddr["addr2"] = "192.168.30.2";

  m_usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(devAddr);

  uhd::usrp::subdev_spec_t rxSpec("A:0");
  m_usrp->set_rx_subdev_spec(rxSpec);

  m_usrp->set_clock_source("external");
  m_usrp->set_time_source("external");
  m_usrp->set_rx_rate(m_sampleRate);  //Sample rate is 500000
```

We prepare for a particular data capture with the following lines.  The set and gets match up with a bit of difference in the decimal points.

```c
  uhd::stream_args_t streamArgs("fc32");
  for (size_t chan = 0; chan < m_usrp->get_rx_num_channels(); chan++)
  {
    streamArgs.channels.push_back(chan);
  }

  m_rxStreamer = m_usrp->get_rx_stream(streamArgs);

  m_usrp->set_rx_gain(m_gainChannel1, 0); // All gains set to 31.5
  m_usrp->set_rx_gain(m_gainChannel2, 1);
  m_usrp->set_rx_gain(m_gainChannel3, 2);

  uhd::time_spec_t cmdTime = m_usrp->get_time_now() + uhd::time_spec_t(1.0);
  m_usrp->set_command_time(cmdTime);
  m_usrp->set_rx_freq(m_freqChannel1 - CENTER_FREQ_OFFSET_HZ, 0); // Freq is 400000000 and CENTER_FREQ is 100000
  m_usrp->set_rx_freq(m_freqChannel2 - CENTER_FREQ_OFFSET_HZ, 1);
  m_usrp->set_rx_freq(m_freqChannel3 - CENTER_FREQ_OFFSET_HZ, 2);
  m_usrp->clear_command_time();

  sleep(1);

  double actualChannel0Freq = m_usrp->get_rx_freq(0);
  double actualChannel1Freq = m_usrp->get_rx_freq(1);
  double actualChannel2Freq = m_usrp->get_rx_freq(2);

  LOG(INFO) << "Acutal tuned USRP frequencies " << std::fixed << actualChannel0Freq << " " << actualChannel1Freq << " " << actualChannel2Freq;
```

When it is time when the start to get the data out using:

```c
      uhd::rx_metadata_t md;
      double timeout = 5.0;

        size_t samplesRxThisTime = m_rxStreamer->recv(buffPtrs, sampsThisTime, md, timeout);

        // Smaller timeout for subsequent packets
        timeout = 0.75;

        // Handle any error codes
        if (md.error_code == uhd::rx_metadata_t::ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
        {
          LOG(ERROR) << "Timed out while receiving data from USRPs";
          break;
        }
```

I had expected that changing the frequency by a small bit wouldn't cause issues.  The original frequency works... the updated frequency doesn't.

Comment: I should note...  When I offset by a small amount say 350Hz the code works.  If I offset by a larger amount like 2000Hz it fails.  I need it to get to 18000Hz offset.

Answer (score 1):

The type of device you are might matter. It looks like a network interface to the device. Is this an N3xx?

I have seen issues similar to this with the B210 where a large frequency change can cause extra delays. In that case, a large frequency re-tune requires re-calibration which is fairly time-consuming.

If you update this with the type of device, someone might be better able to help you. In the meantime you might look into what happens in the RF frontend when you request a re-tune.